# How to create a common base_url() or site_url() in jqm or phonegap?

Tags: jquery, url, jquery-mobile, cordova

i have created a android app for a website .the app consist of many html pages and i also used the website url many times in the app for ajax call to fetch data.so, if i want to change the the website url i have to do it in all the mobile app pages.

So how can i create a variable or object for the url and use it commonly in all my pages of app?-- created app using phonegap and jqm.

Comment: You can create page of configuration and declare all the variable inside it.

Comment: is there any reference or documentation for it .

Comment: No reference or documentation for it you can create as per your requirement

Comment: @Harry ya i have did that is there any proper way to do it like when the app installed it request for the site url and configuration settings.

Comment: including a file of config variables or config object is no different in principle than including libraries like jQuery and jQm. Or just add them in a script tag without a file

Comment: hmmm so i have to create a file to set the configuration of the app manually and check the app configuration set true or not. anyway i just wanna check if there any plugin or inbuilt function in jqm or phonegap for app configuration.